# Python Gurobi: Adding constraints without for loops

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

I am trying to solve a hub location problem in python using the Gurobi solver. The problem I currently have is that my model is very slow, this is partially due to the size of the model but i think my model could be formulated smarter.

Currently I add my constraints in the following way:

```
for i in N:
    for c in C:
        for j in N:
            for p in P:
                if i != j:
                    model.addConstr(grb.quicksum(t[i,j,m,c,p] for m in N if m != j) + grb.quicksum(x[i,j,k,j,c,p] for k in N if k != j) + h[i,j,j,c,p] + d[i,j,c,p] == o[i,j,c,p])
```

I have been told that this could be done in a different way by avoiding all those for loops, and that that might be faster, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this. Does anyone maybe have any advice for me?

Comment: you can use itertools.product to avoid for loops, however I don't think it will make your program faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would collect the two inner sums. I would also consider transforming this into a generator expression using grb.Model.addConstrs like the following:

```
model.addConstrs(
  (grb.quicksum(t[i,j,k,c,p]+x[i,j,k,j,c,p] for k in N if k != j) +
   h[i,j,j,c,p] + d[i,j,c,p] == o[i,j,c,p]
     for i in N
     for c in C
     for j in N
     for p in P
     if i != j),
  "myFlowConstraint")
```

Better yet, if d and o are dictionaries defined over all i,c,j,p with i != j, then you can simplify this to:

```
model.addConstrs(
  (grb.quicksum(t[i,j,k,c,p]+x[i,j,k,j,c,p] for k in N if k != j) +
   h[i,j,j,c,p] + d[i,j,c,p] == o[i,j,c,p]
     for i,j,c,p in d.keys()),
  "myFlowConstraint")
```

I have no data to test this sample for typos, but this should give you the idea.